# Проблема с работой JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

Я делаю небольшие утилиты на *Java(Swing)*. Сейчас хочу перенести их на *JavaFX* и происходит ошибка:

```
 Error:(3, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist
 Error:(4, 19) java: package javafx.fxml does not exist
 Error:(5, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
 Error:(6, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
 Error:(7, 20) java: package javafx.stage does not exist
 Error:(9, 27) java: cannot find symbol
   symbol: class Application
 Error:(16, 23) java: cannot find symbol
   symbol:   class Stage
   location: class RandomName.Main
 Error:(12, 9) java: cannot find symbol
   symbol:   method launch(java.lang.String[])
   location: class RandomName.Main
 Error:(15, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a                          
   supertype
 Error:(17, 9) java: cannot find symbol
   symbol:   class Parent
   location: class RandomName.Main
 Error:(17, 23) java: cannot find symbol
   symbol:   variable FXMLLoader
   location: class RandomName.Main
 Error:(17, 39) java: cannot find symbol
   symbol:   method getClass()
   location: class RandomName.Main
 Error:(19, 35) java: cannot find symbol
   symbol:   class Scene
   location: class RandomName.Main
```

Я работаю в *Intelij Idea Ultimate*, при создании нового проекта все работает нормально, при одинаковом коде (Который генерируется при создании проекта *JavaFX*). Делаю все по документации. Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблеммы, мне потребовалось зайти в `Project Structure -> Global Libraries` и добавить `JavaFX`. После этих манипуляций моя программа компилируется и запускается.